# Getting user information from Facebook AccessToken via GET Req

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it me or is the facebook API documentation horrible and non-newbie friendly?

I am trying to get my users information after he logs in through my react-native app. After pressing the Log in Button the user grants permission to the app and I get and AccessToken back.

I am stuck on how to get the actual information from the user!
I know I have to use the Graph API and I am able to retrieve some information using the Graph API explorer.

However, I have no clue on:

1. how to retrieve the users profile picture
2. how to pass in the access token when doing the request

Can someone help me with this?

I dont understand how facebook can make such a simple thing such a complicated matter.

Comment: Opinions on the documentation differ ... I for one find it quite ok for the most part. Whether it _had_ to be newbie-friendly in the first place is up for discussion IMHO; if you want to write apps for a platform with a billion users, then I’d say it is fair enough to expect that you step to the plate with some sort of developer background, and not use the platform as your “my first hello world app” training playground ... And this just is a complex eco system, so one might have to read more than the one page to get an idea of how the whole system works.

Comment: Anyway, to the issue at hand ... are you using any SDK/lib/framework to make your API requests, or are you just basically making HTTP requests “on your own”? If the former, it should be in the documentation for that SDK/library, how you pass the access token; if the latter, I recommend you read the chapter on basic API usage, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/ And how to get the user’s current profile pic is explained here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/